# Java Library for Fitting Cubic Splines with Fixed Knots?

Tags: python, java, statistics

I'm looking for a Java library to fit a Univariate Spline to a set of two dimensional points.

SciPy LSQUnivariateSpline accomplishes exactly what I want in python, but I haven't been able to find a similar library in Java. The actual implementation here also hinges on

The closest thing I have found in Java is [JSML Math BsLeastSquares](https://docs.roguewave.com/en/imsl/java/7.3/manual/api/com/imsl/math/BsLeastSquares.html), but the project is commercial and I'd like to avoid that if possible.